# change background of individual list item?

Tags: html, css

so im building a webpage currently, and as a request every menu has to have a different color. but im having a but of a struggle figuring out how i target the individual list item.

heres the structure:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>red</li>
        <li>blue</li>
        <li>orange</li>
        <li>yellow</li>
        <li>green</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

the items have some padding and borderradius but i can't figure out how i give the different items a different backgroundcolor the easiest way.

Please help me ;)

thanks in advance.

Comment: Thomas, do you want each of your <li> to have a different color ?

Comment: @KheemaPandey isnt Sass is bit hard for someone who is asking this type of question? No offence to Thomas

Comment: @Aaron my assumption is SASS will be much more benefical instead of using `nth-child`.

Comment: @Thomas, if you have a definitive set of links and want to give a different color each item, then you can use a simple CSS tag. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/brijeshb/34zj7o0d/

Comment: @Thomas check this example. http://sassmeister.com/gist/413419cdbdd1b9d58de3

Comment: @bhh yeah every item has to have a different color ive tryed nth-child but it does not seem to work. :/

Comment: SASS is not an option, i want to use html and css only for this if it is possible.

Comment: then there is Pure css trick you have to use `liner-gradient` to achieve the desire effect.

Answer (score 1):

If it is fixed then you can achieve like below using `nth-child` selector.

```
ul.test li:nth-child(1)
{
 background:red;
}
ul.test li:nth-child(2)
{
 background:blue;
}
ul.test li:nth-child(3)
{
  background:orange;
}
ul.test li:nth-child(4)
{
  background:yellow;
}
ul.test li:nth-child(5)
{
background:green;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hthr9b1v/)

Comment: still its a limited solution, what if OP ad more links.

Comment: Then the OP needs to use JavaScript to make this easier; with the restriction of CSS only he's limited to `:first-child()`, `:last-child()`, `:nth-child()`, `:nth-last-child()`, `:nth-of-type()` and `:nth-last-of-type()`; all of which are ridiculously limited.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better solution may be to avoid having a `<ul>` in the `<nav>`, then style anchor links directly. You avoid having styles for the link items sprawled over multiple style selectors (`ul`, `li`, `a`), and the markup is much cleaner.

```
<nav>
    <a href="home.html">Home</a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a href="whatever.html">Whatever</a>
</nav>
```

The CSS is also short, semantic and easy to understand without guessing:

```
nav > a {
    display: inline-block;   /* or block, depending on design */
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 20px;           /* here rather than in <li> */
    margin: 10px;            /* here rather than in <li> */
    border-radius: 5px;      /* here rather than in <li> */
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;   /* remove default underline */
}
nav > a[href="home.html"] {
    background-color: red;
}
nav > a[href="about.html"] {
    background-color: green;
}
nav > a[href="contact.html"] {
    background-color: blue;
}
nav > a[href="whatever.html"] {
    background-color: violet;
}
```

Personally, I think this is better than using `nth-child`, especially if you add nav items in between other nav items later on. Although `nth-child` works, it is not entirely clear which background is being controlled for which link.

Comment: this answer could be the solution of OP's problem

Answer (score 0):

To style the *nth* item, use the following CSS:

```
li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #f00; /* Whatever you want */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [CSS Selector Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) The `:nth-of-type(n)` and `:nth-child(n)` part